# I have some question about Smart Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, blocks

1. Where is the Smart Contract Data stored?
2. How does it get activated, as every contract has a logical outcome?
3. What happens to the block or the transaction in which the smart contract has been concluded?
4. Linked to #1, how do we access the data in a smart contract?
5. On what grounds does more than one transactions become a part of a block?

Example: We have a salary slip tied up in a smart contract for you. Salary slips are confidential and can only be seen by the person whose that slip is.
Now if company generates a transaction with a smart contract, which should be view able only on the 3th of every month.

How will be the functional flow , and what does company have to give you to access your slip

Comment: Try to make a single question, also make a search because some of those were already answered.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your comment and can you please give me a link for above question

Comment: For the first one https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/how-is-contract-storage-arranged.

Comment: @ismael and the second one? can you give me a all links

Comment: I'd recommend to first read [Ethereum's White Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) and then formulate more specific question.

Comment: There's a search at the top which you can use to search previously answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

1 - If you mean all contract data (that makes the state), it is stored on the nodes in a separate data structure.

2 - As a result of a transaction from an address on the chain.

3 - Becomes part of the chain of block which has the transaction.

4 - Public data can be accessed directly by calling the data get.

5 - Depends on how the miner wants to do it, but with number of pending transactions or the block gas limit as the limiting factors on the chain. Usually miners try to add as much transactions as possible.

6 - Yes, they are part of the respective transactions/blocks that created that  data.

7 - They don't self activate. They activate due to a transaction.

8 - Do you mean a private chain of ethereum or a new blockchain from scratch. If a private, then basically everything is same as ethereum except the genesis block and the parameters.

Comment: can you explain me one by one or please give me a reference link thankz for your answer